# How To Get Variable From Constructor So It Can Be Used In Other Functions?

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
<?php

class Email{
    public $mandrill_host;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->config_ini = parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.ini', true);
        $this->mandrill_host = $config_ini['mandrill']['host'];

    }

    public function sendEmail () {
        $res = $this->mandrill_host;
        return $res;    
    }
}

$test = new Email;
echo $test->sendEmail ();

?>
```

and it gives me an empty result. it seems that the constructor method doesn't give the variable needed in `sendEmail` function. even though I already declared as public variable in class level.

how to get `$this->mandrill_host` from constructor so I can use it in any other method? what did I miss here?

Comment: You know how to access class properties. So what the heck do you do here: `$config_ini['mandrill']['host'];`. If you have error-reporting turned on you will get an error.

Comment: Your logic is broken. Instead of parsing the `.ini` file in the constructor, simply **give** a proper array with valid information to the constructor. Therefore, if ini parsing failed or contains invalid stuff, your object isn't created. Also what @Rizier123 said - you're using `$config_ini` instead of `$this->config_ini`. Naturally, it won't yield results..

Comment: @Rizier123 : nice catch bro. thanks!

Comment: Also, no point making properties public.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class Email{
    public $mandrill_host;
    public $config_ini; //you are missing this

    public function __construct() {
        $this->config_ini = parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.ini', true);
        $this->mandrill_host = $this->config_ini['mandrill']['host'];

    }

    public function sendEmail () {
        $res = $this->mandrill_host;
        return $res;    
    }
}

$test = new Email;
echo $test->sendEmail ();

?>
```